# Advice on choice of epigram

Tags: non-fiction, quotes

I am writing a paper on Internet censorship in China and was considering starting it with a thought provoking epigram to draw the reader.

The title of the paper in question is:

> China's Internet Censorship: Protecting or Controlling?

The epigram I was leaning towards was:

> "Information is not to be feared and ideas are not enemies to be
>   crushed" (Dorgan 2010)

Does this suit the purpose?

Comment: Do you have other choices? it's a bit difficult to judge in isolation.

Comment: Suitable and effective for what?  It would help if you provided us your thesis and whether this epigram is supposed to support your thesis, oppose it, or merely be thought-provoking.

Answer (score 3):

If it effectively summarizes/reflects/prefaces the theme and import of your own paper, then yes.